# node JS passport An error occurs in the if statement when checking membership information

Tags: mysql, passport.js

When checking member information through sql, there is no error if the done part has a hash tag once or twice. However, if you add the done part 3 below as an else statement,
the "error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" appears. Is there a solution?

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.key);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    conn.query(sql, (err, users) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(users[i].key === id) {
          return done(null, users[i]);
        }
      }
    });
});


/* passport local callback */
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {
    let uid = username;
    let pwd = password;
    /* Check member information */
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';
    conn.query(sql, (err, users) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(uid === users[i].id) {
          if(pwd === users[i].password) {
            done(null, users[i]); // *** 1 ***
          } else {
            done(null, false); // *** 2 ***
          }
        } else {
          done(null, false); // here is the error *** 3 ***
        }
      }
    })
  }
));

/* passport local login */
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate(
    'local', 
    {
      successRedirect: '/friends',
      failureRedirect: '/login',
      failureFlash: true
    }
  )
);
```